# Parsing nested json payload python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get only value A from from this nested json payload.

**My function:**

```
import requests
import json
def payloaded():
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen("www.example.com/payload.json") as r:
    data = json.loads(r.read().decode(r.headers.get_content_charset("utf-8")))
text = (data["bod"]["id"])
print(text)
```

**The payload:**

```
bod: {
id: [
    {
        value: "A",
        summary: "B",
        format: "C"
    }
  ]
},
```

Currently it is returning everything within the brackets [... value ... summary ... format ...]

**Solution found:**

```
def payloaded():
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen("www.example.com/payload.json") as r:
    data = json.loads(r.read().decode(r.headers.get_content_charset("utf-8")))
text = (data["bod"]["id"][0]["value"])
print(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `id` value is a list (even though it just contains a single value), you'll need to go inside it with a list indexer. Since lists in Python are zero-indexed (they start from zero) you'll use `[0]` to extract the first element:

```
data["bod"]["id"][0]["value"]
```

Comment: Thanks! I came to the same solution as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def payloaded():
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen("www.example.com/payload.json") as r:
    data = json.loads(r.read().decode(r.headers.get_content_charset("utf-8")))
text = (data["bod"]["id"][0]["value"])
print(text)
```