# Extract and format Values from nested json data

Tags: python, json, extract

I am trying to extract some data from the json data frame below, using Python 2.7.9.

I am trying to get to the counts in a single row that are listed inside the "steps" list using the code below:

```
data2 = (json.loads(data));

for data_key,data_value in data2['data'].items():
for date_key,date_value in data_value.items():
    for steps_value in date_value:
        if 'steps' == date_key:    #looping on dictionary object
            print data_key,steps_value['count'],steps_value['event'],steps_value['custom_event']
```

On digging further, I managed to make some progress and get to the values. I am not a Python expert, so wondering if this could be done in a more elegant manner.Still looking to get to the output as below.

Ideal Output format:
Date1 Step1 Count1 Step2 Count2
Date2 Step2 Count1 Step2 Count2

Sample Data frame:

```
"frame": 
{"dates": ["2016-09-12", "2016-09-19", "2016-09-26"]}, 
"data": {
    "2016-09-12": 
        {"steps": [
            {"count": 325788, "step_conv_ratio": 1, "goal": "App Open", "overall_conv_ratio": 1, "avg_time": null, "event": "App Open"}, 
            {"count": 20524, "step_conv_ratio": 0.627875673029858, "goal": "Game Played", 
            "avg_time": 572, "event": "Game Played"}], 
        "analysis": {"completion": 20524, "starting_amount": 32688, "steps": 2, "worst": 1}}, 
    "2016-09-19": 
        {"steps": [
            {"count": 32186, "step_conv_ratio": 1, "goal": "App Open", "overall_conv_ratio": 1, "avg_time": null, "event": "App Open"}, 
            {"count": 20809, "step_conv_ratio": 0.6405528535369082, "goal": "Game Played", 
            "avg_time": 698, "event": "Game Played"}], 
        "analysis": {"completion": 20809, "starting_amount": 32486, "steps": 2, "worst": 1}}, 
    "2016-09-26": 
        {"steps": [
            {"count": 456, "step_conv_ratio": 1, "goal": "App Open", "overall_conv_ratio": 1, "avg_time": null, "event": "App Open"}, 
            {"count": 587, "step_conv_ratio": 0.7873688132646091, "goal": "Game Played", 
            "avg_time": 571, "event": "Game Played"}], 
        "analysis": {"completion": 12679, "starting_amount": 16103, "steps": 2, "worst": 1}}
    }}
```

Any help / suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing nested json payload python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200654/parsing-nested-json-payload-python)

Answer (score 0):

If every date only has two steps you could do something like:

```
stuff = json.loads(data)
dates = stuff["frame"]["dates"] # list of dates as strings
for date in dates:
    steps = stuff["data"][date]["steps"] # list of dicts
    print("{0}: step 1: {1}, step 2: {2}".format(date, steps[0]["count"], steps[1]["count"]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I can try this out.But the number of dates can vary depending on the type of request.  Currently, I am just trying to loop through each of them to get to the data.